# Проблема с background-image в Interner Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background

При попытке сверстать учебный лендинг, возникли проблемы при отображении бэкграунд изображения первого (верхнего) листа. Возникли, само собой, в Internet Explorer. Для наглядности сперва два скриншота: [первый](http://s014.radikal.ru/i329/1603/1b/a743dd71aba0.jpg) - примерно одинаково отображается в Firefox, Chrome и Opera, [второй](http://s018.radikal.ru/i521/1603/a1/a6f8e75befb6.jpg) - собственно, IE. При корректной передаче бэкграунд-картинка отображается полностью, подстраиваясь под размер экрана, в то время, как Internet Explorer ее "обрезает" примерно вдвое. Размер самого бэкграунд изображения - 1920х979, разрешение экрана - 1366х768. Собственно код, отвечающий за бэкграунд в сss ниже:

```
    body {
  background-image: url(/images/background.jpg); 
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  }
```

Заранее благодарен за фидбэк! Не судите строго, только учусь..

Comment: Попробуйте заменить jpg на png

Answer (score 2):

Upd. Решено заменой

```
 background-size: cover;
```

на

```
background-position: 50% 25%;
```